# How to Wrap Flutter and Python and Distribute as Single software?

Tags: python, flutter, fastapi

I am developing a Flutter Desktop App and the API is built on Python Fast API, I want to wrap both as single Software but dont know how to do that.

Right now I have to start Fast API Server and then Flutter App to make it working. I want to deploy them as Single App.

I don't know nothing about it.
Please enlighten me.

Comment: Why do you want to distribute a fast api server alongside the flutter app? Where should the server run, on the same client as the app?? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it must be a good idea to dockerize both FastAPI and Flutter (here’s link for the tutorial for Flutter only https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-dockerize-flutter-apps-f2e54d6ec43c)

It seems to be what you want if you deploy a docker container